# PHP DOMDocument, require first item only

Tags: php, domdocument

Hello I have use DOMDocs in the past but I am stuck how to do this.

```
$xmldoc = new DOMDocument();
$xmldoc->load('http://example.com');
$feeditem = $xmldoc->getElementsByTagName('data');
```

I only want the first instance of the tag 'data'. Ordinarily I would write a foreach loop:

```
foreach($feeditem as $element){ //}
```

and do what i want with each feeditem but here I only want the first $feeditem. $feeditem isn't an array, it's a DOMdoc object so I can't do $feeditem[0] to select the first 'data' tag.

Thank you for any help with this.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If you look up the documentation for `getElementsByTagName`, you can see that it returns a [`DOMNodeList`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnodelist.php). So after reading the documentation for `DOMNodeList`, you should find out that you can use [`$feeditem->item(0)`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domnodelist.item.php).

Comment: thank you for the detailed answer. I wasn not aware of such documentation, thank you.

Answer (score 8):

```
$feeditem->item(0);
```

([reference](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnodelist.php))